# Finding expectation of size of a subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, pr.probability

I have been trying to implement a algorithm but got stuck in finding expectation of the size of the subgraph.

n - size of the network.

d - at most number of communities a node could     participate in.

gamma - fraction of ties of nodes in communities .

k - maximum size of a community.

delta - each community size lies between delta*k and k.

epsilon - It is the gap(If for a node 'u' in a community 'C' 'u' has about alpha edges in the community and for the nodes outside the community it has less than alpha-epsilon fraction of  connections in the community).

S - sub graph.

Γ(v) - neighborhood of of v in graph G.

And my main issue is with the second point which says size of the sample is less than 3 times expected(need some help with how to calculate and its relationship with the equation give below that).

[image]

[Link to the research paper](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~schoeneb/papers/OverlappingCompostsoc.pdf)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a mathematical research problem.

Comment: At first sight, it seems that all the given information except "S - sub graph" refers not to S but to whatever graph (or network) it's a subgraph of.  But in order to say something about the expectation of the size of S, one needs some information about S.  Is *all* the given information to be understood as pertaining directly to S?  If so, what's the point of "sub"?  If not, which part of the information pertains to S and which part pertains to the larger network?

Comment: @Andreas We have information of the network(Γ(v)) from which subgraph S is formed with the probability as shown in the snap shot attached which depends on epsilon, gamma, n and few others. Thanks for taking a look at the problem. I am attaching the research paper from which I posted this question http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~schoeneb/papers/OverlappingCompostsoc.pdf 


Comment: @Brendan Thanks for taking a look at the algorithm, actually this algorithm is from a research paper.

Comment: all the info provided is for the actual main graph lets say G  from from which you choose few nodes based on the condition mentioned and from the nodes chosen lets say one node is 'v' whose neighborhood in G is Γ(v) and from Γ(v) from  which we need to find the subgraph with the probability given.